# Opencv-python install error :Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: none)

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed opencv-python but whenever I try to check that opencv-python is installed or not so it is showing me this

````
```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: none)   
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv```
````

so I try to install it again so what I am getting is

````
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (4.5.2.52)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.20.3)```

can anyone please explain what is the issue?
````

Comment: Well, it's called `opencv-python`, not `opencv`

Comment: I mean, the error message talks about `opencv`, so you're checking whether the `opencv` library is installed, but it's not because the name is `opencv-python`

Comment: It is still not recognisable

Comment: What command are you using to check whether the library is installed?

Comment: simple "opencv-python" in cmd

Comment: Is this the _terminal/cmd command_ you're using? Are you literally running `opencv-python` in the terminal? Please include the full command and its _full_ output in the post.

Comment: actually, I am trying to run a code in VScode but it shows " No module name as cv2" so I tried to uninstall OpenCV and then install it again but what I am getting is OpenCV is not recognisable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (4.5.2.52)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.20.3)
```

that means it is installed

Comment: I know that but whenever I try to check that it is installed or not it always gives me "Opencv is not recognised..."